# Set object reference in Service Android

Tags: android, service, android-mediaplayer

I'm creating a music player app in Android and I'm trying to set up the MediaPlayer as a service so that it persists across all Activities/Fragments. The service code:

```
public class PlayerService extends Service {

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

}

public void LoadUrl(String url){

    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    }  catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //mediaPlayer.start();
    Play(mediaPlayer);
}

public void Play(MediaPlayer player) {
    player.start();
}

public void Pause(MediaPlayer player) {
    player.pause();
}
```

}

and the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

PlayerService playerService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(savedInstanceState != null){

    } else {

         playerService = new PlayerService();
        Intent startPlayer = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);
        startService(startPlayer);

   ....
```

When MainActivity is started, it launches the service, however, when I try to load a Url into the MediaPlayer with:

```
 playerService.LoadUrl(feedItem.getAudioUrl());
```

I get an exception saying that mediaPlayer in the Service is null. How can I make sure that the mediaPlayer is retained?

Comment: you don't have to pass media player as arguments in Play and Pause...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to start the service using startService without onStartCommand in service, without which the sevice won't start. So your media player won't get initialized